# jqGrid events after saving does not fire

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, error-handling

I have a few events set up like this:

```
$('#grid').jqGrid('saveRow', lastsel, 
    { aftersavefunc: function (rowid, response) { alert('after save'); },
    errorfunc: function (rowid, response) { alert('error occured'); } 
});
```

The problem is, they never fire!

**Edit 2**

Moved answer to an acutal answer instead of having it in the question.

Comment: You should consider posting an answer with your Edit, that way everyone else knows that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, problem solved. You have to add the event params also to the 'editRow' call. They are used when saving... truly confusing!

```
$('#grid').jqGrid('editRow', id, { keys: true,  
    aftersavefunc: function (rowid, response) { alert('after save'); }, 
    errorfunc: function (rowid, response) { alert('...we have a problem'); }  
});
```